# Big data restore on from SQL Server Server dump

Tags: sql, sql-server, bigdata

I would like to restore a 4TB SQL Server data dump currently on an external hard drive.

Now here's the problem, the hard drive on most laptops is smaller than this size and given that I don't have a server allocated yet, is there a way I can access this data?

I have SQL Server on my laptop. I would also like more than 1 persons to be able to access this data.

Is there anyway that 3 people can access this data from the hard drive at the same time? We do not have a shared network connection, all users are in different homes. We are all university students fairly new to this stuff, so details would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. What version of SQL server? 2. Do you want people to access this database via SQL server running on your laptop? 3. Do you have access to any other storage that can be attached to your laptop (another external drive or a network share)?

Comment: I don't have access to network share. The data dump has been created using SQL Server 2008. I can have people access the database via SQL server running on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have around $650, you can by yourself a 8TB NAS box.  More than enough space.  Just place it on your network.

[http://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Business-Storage-Attached-STBP8000100/dp/B00B5Q79FW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B5Q79FW)

You could always use some type of cloud (Azure) to restore it.  But might be more hassle since you have to build out a SQL Server on Windows environment, then copy the data, then restore it.

Do not know what the cost would be versus buying a NAS for the project.

**I guess the main question is this a one time or continuing task?**

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. This is a one time task, it will continue for a couple of months, possibly longer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but my problem here is even if I buy a NAS, I don't have a common network connection to share. We are 3 users all in different homes so creating a common network is another issue. We are all university students and fairly new to this admin stuff so any details would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look into virtual machines from Azure or Amazon.  That way you can access the data anywhere with SSMS.  Call to confirm pricing.  http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines

Comment: Get a NAS as suggested in my original answer, restore your data files to the NAS, then set up a VPN to connect the remote locations perferably using the OpenVPN protocol. You will all be able to share the data then. It's a bit of a tall order though - you really want to access a 4TB database over a home internet connection?

Comment: The problem with hosting SQL Server on a laptop is the operating system.  Version 7 or 8 only allows one active RDP connection at a time.  If you install Windows server, you can get two connections via RDP (MSTSC).  The cloud solution allows for more connectivity and can scale when needed.  Again, it all comes down to budget.

Comment: What you could do is install VirtualBox or similar, give each of your users their own OS and install Management Studio in. Configure your firewall to NAT from different ports to the correct virtual instance of windows, and then they can query. Not sure whether your laptop would be smoking at this point though... :D

Comment: @MooMinTroll ROFLOL - Sure anything is possible.  Have you tried running two VMs on a laptop.  Real slow unless you have an i7, plenty of RAM and/or SSD Drives.  Again, the budget and the business case are the drivers to what can be done.

Comment: After reading all the suggestions, I think having this data on the cloud would be the best option. It will cost a bit (The Amazon S3 for storage and EC2 for running SQL Server) but has the most chances of working out eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the space to restore your database you could try using a tool such as Idera SQL Virtual Database:

> http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlvirtualdatabase

This will (apparently) mount a backup and make it look just like a genuine MS SQL database. There's a free trial though I don't know what limitations it has.

Comment: Red Gate used to have the same product, http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/, but it was slashed.  Sob, Sob, Sob.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA - I thought they had something like that from days gone past but couldn't see it in their current product list. Thanks for reminding me.